# Python type checking on a function that returns str or Sequence

Tags: python, sequence, type-hinting, mypy

I have a Python function that processes a sequence, and returns the same sort of sequence. E.g. if it is fed a list of integers, it will return a list of integers, and if it is fed a string, it will return a string.

How do I add type hints for this function?

The following works fine, but is not a very strict type check:

```
from typing import Any, TypeVar, Sequence

_S = Any

def process_sequence(s: _S) -> _S:
    return s

def print_str(word: str):
    print(word)

def print_sequence_of_ints(ints: Sequence[int]):
    for i in ints:
        print(i)

a = process_sequence("spam")
print_str(a)

a = process_sequence([1,2,3,42])
print_sequence_of_ints(a)
```

However, when I try to narrow down `_S`:

`_S = Sequence`

or

`_S = TypeVar('_S', Sequence, str)`

mypy (a type checking code validator) yields the following error:

`error: Argument 1 to "print_str" has incompatible type "Sequence[Any]"; expected "str"`

How can I add a type hint to my function that says the input must be a sequence, and the output has the same type as the input, and make mypy happy at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Sequence

_S = TypeVar('_S', str, Sequence)

def process_sequence(s: _S) -> _S:
    return s

def print_str(word: str):
    print(word)

def print_sequence_of_ints(ints: Sequence[int]):
    for i in ints:
        print(i)

a = process_sequence("spam")
print_str(a)

b = process_sequence([1,2,3,42])
print_sequence_of_ints(b)
```

In this case, mypy is happy. Apparently, in the TypeVar declaration I have to define the more specific `str` before the more generic `Sequence`. (`_S = TypeVar('_S', Sequence, str)` still gives an error)

I also tried to educate mypy using a `# type: str` comment, but that did not work.

Comment: This looks very good, aside the fact that this way I have to manually add support for all sequences (bytes, tuple, list, str, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

`a` is of type `Sequence[Any]` not `str`. If you are sure that `a` will always be a string, you can cast the type with `print_str(cast(str, a))`.

```
_S = Sequence[Any]

def process_sequence(s: _S) -> _S:
    return s

def print_str(word: str):
    print(word)

def print_sequence_of_ints(ints: Sequence[int]):
    for i in ints:
        print(i)

a = process_sequence("spam")
print_str(a)  # a is of type Sequence[Any] not str

a = process_sequence([1,2,3,42])
print_sequence_of_ints(a)
```

You can also use `T = TypeVar('T')` instead of `Sequence[Any]`, but you lose some typing information and protection.

Comment: could you apply logic to this with isinstace("foo", str). would it make any difference in this case? just curious.

Comment: isinstance is not part of the typing information, so mypy won't inferer the type.

Comment: What do you mean with `a` is of type `Sequence[Any]` not `str`. During runtime, `a` is an instance of `str`. Is there are way I can tell mypy it is a str, not a Sequence, without changing the runtime code?

Comment: `a` is `Sequence[Any]` because it was output by a function which return this type. This function can return anything that is of this type, like a `string`, `List` or `Tuples`. Mypy can't be sure you'll end up with a `string`, useless you state it with a `cast(str, a)`. Remember that the type is infered from the typing. Also, `cast` have almost no runtime cost, so use it if you need to. If your function always return a `string` and not a `Sequence[Any]`, change your typing annotation accordingly.